# My Enchanted Bow Command Doesn't Work. MC 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give @p bow 1 0 {ench:[{id:21,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:2000},{id:49,lvl:2000},{id:50,lvl:2000},{id:51,lvl:2000,{id:34,lvl:2000}],display:{Name:"Dead Man Crack",Lore:["This Bow Is Only Effective When Shot At The Butt"]}}
```

This is my command and is it's always saying "unbalanced square brackets".

Does anyone have a answer, a clue or even a hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{id:51,lvl:2000` This is the "unbalanced square brackets". I don't know why minecraft calls these square brackets, but just add a closing curly bracket and that should be all.