# How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Often, when making a command block contraption, you need to set an entity's data tag. These tags can sometimes be *very* long, with many layers of nested curly and square brackets. For example, this is the command to summon a villager with a single custom trade:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:3,Career:2,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:diamond,Count:6b}},sell:{id:minecraft:diamond_hoe,tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:10s}]}]}}
```

The single-line command block interface of Minecraft makes it incredibly difficult to find and fix errors, especially when it comes to mismatched brackets. In fact, for illustration purposes, I put an error in the above command.

**What techniques can I use to find and fix unbalanced square or curly brackets when writing long and complicated data tags?**

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an automated tool for at least checking the structure of data tags.  Perhaps this should be rectified.

Comment: @MBraedley yeah, I'm a bit surprised myself. Minecraft's lenient JSON parsing makes most regular JSON checkers complain.

Comment: Just a question, since this is clearly for all the "what's wrong with my command?" questions, should the question title be re-worded to match something a bit more google-search relative?

Comment: For reference, I provided basically this exact solution on this question here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207989/unbalanced-curly-brackets-error-with-this-command-block-code-what-am-i-doing

Comment: ^Heh, just realised @MrLemon - you even [commented](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207989/unbalanced-curly-brackets-error-with-this-command-block-code-what-am-i-doing#comment310528_229160) on it :)

Comment: @Robotnik I suggest you re-post that here - it is always good to have multiple approaches, and your answer seems to explain the process better.

Comment: @MrLemon Been meaning to write one of these, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @angussidney - I will if I get more support to do so, but tbh one of the questions should be made a duplicate of the other. As I said on the [meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11572/28182), I'm not really fussed which way the duplicate goes (and there's a meta/precedent that we don't just dupe newer->older, it's based on quality), but both questions are effectively solving the same problem.

Comment: @Ben this really only solves a single specific issue (mismatched brackets). But I agree, I should put that in the title.

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way to find mismatched braces is to expand the command into a multi-line format with properly indented lines. This makes it easier to find errors and subsequently fix them.

A nifty little tool to automatically format your data tags can be found at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. Using the <kbd>Format</kbd> and <kbd>Remove White Space</kbd> buttons, you can expand or collapse your command, respectively. Using the sample data tag given in the questions, we can turn this

```
{Profession:3,Career:2,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:diamond,Count:6b}},sell:{id:minecraft:diamond_hoe,tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:10s}]}]}}
```

into this

```
{
  Profession: 3,
  Career: 2,
  Offers: {
    Recipes: [
      {
        buy: {
          id: minecraft: diamond,
          Count: 6b
        }
      },
      sell: {
        id: minecraft: diamond_hoe,
        tag: {
          ench: [
            {
              id: 16s,
              lvl: 10s
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now all that is left is compare the opening and closing brackets at each indentation level. You can see that there is *no* closing bracket at the last indentation level, the last bracket is indented once, showing us that there is a closing bracket missing on some level.

If you check all the tags starting at the top, you can see that there's a problem with the `sell` tag: There's a closing square bracket instead of a curly bracket on that indentation level. To make this even more visible, we can copy-paste our data tag into an advanced text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which highlights matching brackets for us:

Have the missing curly bracket problem:

[image: notepad++ view]

Here it is immediately apparent that a closing curly bracket is needed for the `sell` tag.

Without the missing bracket:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit of info: I don't think that any formatting is needed, unless you have a 1000+ character command.
For begining Minecraft "programmers" I would recommend copying the command to Notepar/Gedit, finding the most indent brackets and deleting their **content**, then deleting the contents of the brackets "under" those and repeat untill they find a missing/wrongly placed pair.
For more advanced users I'd recommend doing it as I do: just thinking out the bracket pairs. By this way, I (and anyone else can) found the mistake in the example command in like 10 seconds without seeing the existinbg answer.

Hope was helpfull!