# I can't get a villager to sell adventure mode items with names or 'CanPlaceOn' tags

Tags: minecraft-commands

I can't get this command to work:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Proffesion: 0,CustomName: “Ratigan”, CustomNameVisible: 1,Career: 1,CareerLevel: 42,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:pumpkin},{id:minecraft:iron_block,Count:3},{id:minecraft:pumpkin}},sell:{id:minecraft:lever,Count:1,tage:CustomName:["SEcret passage under the well"],tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}}}]}
```

It says: `Unbalanced curly brackets {}`, but I can't seem to find where I messed up. Can somebody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I am not well versed in the command-block syntax, but you have surrounded your "buy" with curly braces, but not your sell, so as the error suggests your curly braces are unbalanced

should

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Proffesion: 0,CustomName: “Ratigan”, CustomNameVisible: 1,Career: 1,CareerLevel: 42,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:pumpkin},{id:minecraft:iron_block,Count:3},{id:minecraft:pumpkin}},sell:{id:minecraft:lever,Count:1,tage:CustomName:["SEcret passage under the well"],tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}}}]}
```

be

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Proffesion: 0,CustomName: “Ratigan”, CustomNameVisible: 1,Career: 1,CareerLevel: 42,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:pumpkin},{id:minecraft:iron_block,Count:3},{id:minecraft:pumpkin}},{sell:{id:minecraft:lever,Count:1,tage:CustomName:["SEcret passage under the well"],tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}}}]}
```

emphasis on the sell part, you have `... },sell:{id:m ...` where it should be `... },{sell:{id:m ...`