# Problem with The Curly Brackets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
testfor @a 
{
    Inventory:
    [{
        id:"minecraft:stained_hardened_clay",Damage:14s,Count:5
    }]
} 
/setblock ~ ~ ~ air
```

Minecraft keeps telling me that there is something wrong with the amount of curly brackets

Comment: Your entire syntax just looks way off. For example, you're meant to start with the `/`. That's likely a big part of what is throwing it all out

Comment: and none of your strings (words) are surrounded by double-quotes

Comment: so basically i have to "Damage" and "Count" or what? D:

Comment: Ok, we should step back a bit here. the data-tag format uses JSON syntax. This is a way to represent data for a computer program (in this case Minecraft) to interpret. Have a quick browse of [This Intro to JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) to get an idea of how things should be formatted so that Minecraft will understand them correctly. Further, the answer on this question will also help you debug this: [How can I fix “unbalanced brackets” in my data tag?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Comment: Could be that im a bit retarded but i see exactly 2 open Curly Brackets and 1 open square bracket in between. And they are all closed at the end.
I think im just retarrded

Comment: @Robotnik This is actually using the [NBT format](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format), not JSON. While visually similar in written form, it is much different. Key names do not use quotes, differing datatypes can be declared (such as the "14s" indicating a signed short with a value of 14), and string values do not need quotes if the value cannot be interpreted as another datatype.

Comment: @MeISwear What version are you using and are you using vanilla? The command is structurally correct as far as balancing goes. The `Count` tag has the wrong datatype declaration (needs to be `Count:5b` instead of `Count:5`), but that won't cause your error. Also ensure the command block is actually running by checking the time in the Last Output box.

Comment: Ok. I changed all this but its the same old Error.

`[10:10:19] Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced curly brackets {}: Inventory:[{"id":"minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","Damage":14s,"Count":5b}]} /setblock ~ ~ ~ air`

                         i noticed that the { in front of the Inventory is missing in the Error. Why is that?

Comment: Oh wait, did you put the `/setblock` command at the end of `/testfor` and not in another command block? I thought you had it as a separate command. You can't just add a command at the end of another one (well, except `/execute` which was built for that purpose, but is not useful in your case). You need to have each command in their own command block.

Comment: @Ben Commands in a command block do not need the opening `/`.

Answer (score 0):

so I removed `/setblock ~ ~ ~ air` and it gave no errors

also `testfor` only tests, it won't run commands after the test

I'd suggest using `/scoreboard players set <player> <objective> <score> [dataTag]` then you can use `score_<objective>[_min]=<x>` on a selector (`@a @e @r @p`)

I got this to work, but as I said, this will only test (for conditional command blocks and comparators)

```
testfor @a 
{
    Inventory:
    [{
        id:"minecraft:stained_hardened_clay",Damage:14s,Count:5b
    }]
}
```

so your main problem was the `/setblock`