# Enchant dandelion in 1.7 minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I try to use this command in command block in 1.7.9 version but it isn't working, why?

```
/give @p yellow_flower 1 0 {display:{Name:"Mleczyk",Lore:[Mlecz za AlphaTesty, -Sid Leniwiec]}},{ench:[{id:34,lvl:1]}
```

Comment: any other information? Error messages? Logs etc?

Comment: Why are you even in 1.7?

Comment: im in 1.7 beacouse my server be in it and some plugins work only in 1.7

Comment: 27/5000
and what should it look like?

Comment: but without {ench:[{id:34,lvl:1]} its working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag) and [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command)

Answer (score 1):

When fixing stuff it is a good idea to split up the command in multiple lines, so you can actually see what's wrong.

You missed a bracket and the Lore String needs to be encased in quotes when using more than one word:

```
/give @p yellow_flower 1 0 {
   display:{
      Name:"Mleczyk",
      Lore:[
          Mlecz za AlphaTesty,  <-- Quotes " "
          -Sid Leniwiec         <-- Quotes " "
        ]
     }
 },                             <-- closed too soon
 {                              <-- ench doesn't need to be encased
   ench:[
       {id:34,lvl:1             <-- Closing Bracket  } 
     ]
 }
```

Fixed:

```
/give @p yellow_flower 1 0 {display:{Name:"Mleczyk",Lore:["Mlecz za AlphaTesty", "-Sid Leniwiec"]},ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}
```

Comment: i have error: Encountered multiple top tags, only one expected

Comment: i did it       /give @p yellow_flower 1 0 {display:{Name:"Mleczyk",Lore:["Mlecz za AlphaTesty", "-Sid Leniwiec"]},ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}

Comment: oops, you're right.. forgot that one bracket. fixed