# Why is Minecraft giving me a 'data tag parsing failed' error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to work on a map for some time now, but a lot of commands involving things like command signs with formatted text or armorstands refuse to work.

Take my most recent test, where I used mrgaretto's armor stand positioner to try to make a custom object. It didn't work and supplied this error:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got '<EOF>' at: ...e commandBlockOutput false"},{id:co<--[HERE]
```

The full sentence regarding the area that it says is incorrect is this:

gamerul**e commandBlockOutput false"},{id:co**mmandblock_minecart,

Now, I know enough about Minecraft coding that putting a } in the middle of the word 'commandblock_minecart' makes no sense and won't fix any issues. And as far as I'm concerned, the armor stand command (which simply summons a grass block) is fine. And, just as a final test, I even tried putting the } in the spot where it asked me to...

and it supplied the exact same error. So is my client broken or something?

For those of who that would like to see the full code:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~1.0 ~ 
{
  Block:stone,
  Time:1,
  Passengers:
  [
    {
      id:falling_block,
      Block:redstone_block,
      Time:1,
      Passengers:
      [
        {
          id:falling_block,
          Block:activator_rail,
          Time:1,
          Passengers:
          [
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:gamerule commandBlockOutput false
            },
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:summon armor_stand ~0.0 ~-3.66437 ~0.191406 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:ladder}]}
            },
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:summon armor_stand ~0.0 ~-4.07062 ~0.191406 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:ladder}]}
            },
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:setblock ~ ~ ~1.0 command_block 0 replace {Command:fill ~ ~-3 ~-1 ~ ~ ~ air}
            },
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:setblock ~ ~-1 ~1.0 redstone_block
            },
            {
              id:commandblock_minecart,
              Command:kill @e[type=commandblock_minecart,r=1]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Comment: @pppery The command seems to not have unbalanced brackets, so this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @bearb001 Ah yes, that is correct. The fact that the question had an (apparently wrong) answer that said "just add a `}`" made me think it was a simple unbalanced brackets case.

Comment: Have you tried to put the commands into quotation marks? Like so: `Command:"gamerule commandBlockOutput false"`

Comment: To those voting to close due to this question being unclear, this question is not unclear, it has a command and an error for that command and the question is, why this error occurs. The only possibly unclear thing is what version of minecraft is being used.

Comment: The version is 12.2.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if somebody could help out or look into this. I can't really make the map if I can't solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

At {id : commandblockminecart , ... By analysing the error I believe you were supposed to type '}' there instead of this id.