# Villager trader and custom written book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im trying to get my villager to trade a written book i keep getting this err
Expected '}' at position 223: author:me}<--[HERE}

this is the script

/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},CustomName:"\"wii\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:1},sell:{id:written_book,Count:1,pages:['{"text":"test"}'],title:nono,author:me}:{display:{Name:"\"sand\""}}},maxUses:9999999}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Minecraft commands, but it seems to me that you are not closing the `:[{buy:` part of the script, the `]` is nowhere to be seen, also I couldn't make this a comment since I don't have 50 rep yet ;P